# Calculating root mean square velocity using current vs time graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current

There was a question in my today's physics exam. Me and my friend had conflicting views about the question. Here is the graph and the question is "Calculate the value of I<sub>rms</sub> using following graph."

[image]

Here is my solution:

Since I<sub>rms</sub>= Peak value/$\sqrt{2}$....

Hence I<sub>rms</sub> =$\frac {2}{\sqrt{2}}$ = $\sqrt2$

Here is my friend's solution:

I<sub>rms</sub> = $\sqrt{\frac{I1^2 + I2^2+...}{n}}$

Hence I<sub>rms</sub>=$\sqrt{\frac{4+4}{2}} = 2$

I was just thinking He was right because the formula I applied was for wave form current (sine wave). Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Yes your friend is right. As you said your way was for sin or cos functions only.

Comment: Yes I got that at once when i left the hall... I thought this formula won't be valid because in the wave form of AC, there is not constant peak current, its lower most of the times. hence the I<sub>rms</rms> current would be higher in the problem than in the wave form.

Comment: what are you really asking for then?Question not clear.

Comment: no no... you are right.. This was just a form of saying thanks :D.. I was just saying that I figured that out but was not sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write the current as a function of time, $I(t)$, then the root mean square current is:

$$ I_\text{RMS}^2 = \frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau I^2(t)dt $$

where $\tau$ is the period of the waveform. In this case $I$ is always $\pm 2$ so $I^2$ is always $4$ and the integral becomes:

$$ I_\text{RMS}^2 = \frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau 4dt = \frac{1}{\tau} 4\tau = 4 $$

So $I_\text{RMS} = 2$.

I would beware of trying to use apparently intuitive arguments in exams. Just feed the information you're given into the equation that you know applies and you'll get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is quite different.

Initially, find the $I_{avg}$ for the 1st half and then for the second half, i.e.

$$I_{RMS}^2 = \frac{\int I^2 dt}{T}$$

Where the integral is initially from 0 to T/2 and then from T/2 to T, so that

\begin{align}
I_{RMS}^2 &= \frac{I_0^2(T/2) + I_0^2(T/2)}{T} \\
                     &= I_0^2
\end{align}

Here $I_0 = 2 \text{ A}$.
So $I_{RMS}^2 = 4 \text{ A}^2$;
$I_{RMS} = \sqrt{4} = 2 \text{ A}$.

Hope it helps you.